# extracting strings from a file

Tags: java

Hi i have written a java program to get molecular function and biological process from a file if ID matches but im gettin *StringIndexOutofBoundsException*.
can any one please correct it? Thanks in advance.
 Here is my input:

```
chr11   RAP3_rep    mRNA    17114958    17117968    .   +   .   ID=Os11t0448200-01;Name=Os11t0448200-01;Gene_symbols=AM14;GO=Molecular Function: protein kinase activity (GO:0004672),Molecular Function: ATP binding (GO:0005524),Biological Process: protein amino acid phosphorylation (GO:0006468),Molecular Function: protein tyrosine kinase activity (GO:0004713),Molecular Function: protein serine/threonine kinase activity (GO:0004674);ID_converter=Os11g0448200;InterPro=Protein kinase, core (IPR000719),Tyrosine protein kinase (IPR001245),Serine/threonine protein kinase (IPR002290),Serine/threonine protein kinase, active site (IPR008271),Protein kinase-like (IPR011009),Serine/threonine protein kinase-related (IPR017442);Link_to=8185 (Oryzabase),Protein kinase%2C core (Plant Gene Family Database);Locus_id=Os11g0448200;Note=Arbuscular mycorrhizal specific marker 14.;ORF_evidence=Q53JE9 (UniProt);Transcript_evidence=Inferred from reference;Sequence_download=Os11t0448200-01;References=19033527%2C 15905328;Status=manual curation (Oct 29%2C 2010)
chr11   RAP3_rep    CDS 17114958    17115039    .   +   .   Parent=Os11t0448200-01
chr11   RAP3_rep    CDS 17115846    17115869    .   +   .   Parent=Os11t0448200-01
chr11   RAP3_rep    CDS 17115970    17116095    .   +   .   Parent=Os11t0448200-01
chr11   RAP3_rep    CDS 17116205    17116546    .   +   .   Parent=Os11t0448200-01
chr11   RAP3_rep    CDS 17116669    17116784    .   +   .   Parent=Os11t0448200-01
chr11   RAP3_rep    CDS 17116880    17117140    .   +   .   Parent=Os11t0448200-01
chr11   RAP3_rep    CDS 17117589    17117786    .   +   .   Parent=Os11t0448200-01
chr11   RAP3_rep    CDS 17117891    17117968    .   +   .   Parent=Os11t0448200-01
chr11   RAP3_rep    mRNA    17565866    17568694    .   -   .   ID=Os11t0455500-01;Name=Os11t0455500-01;Alias=AK059712,AK060299,AK119539,AK122115;ID_converter=Os11g0455500;Link_to=S-adenosyl-L-homocysteine hydrolase (Plant Gene Family Database);Locus_id=Os11g0455500;NIAS_FLcDNA=001-032-F05;Note=Similar to Adenosylhomocysteinase-like protein.;ORF_evidence=Q84VE1 (UniProt);Transcript_evidence=AK059712 (DDBJ%2C Best hit);Sequence_download=Os11t0455500-01;InterPro=NAD(P)-binding (IPR016040),S-adenosyl-L-homocysteine hydrolase (IPR000043),S-adenosyl-L-homocysteine hydrolase%2C NAD binding (IPR015878);GO=Molecular Function: catalytic activity (GO:0003824),Molecular Function: binding (GO:0005488),Biological Process: metabolic process (GO:0008152),Molecular Function: adenosylhomocysteinase activity (GO:0004013),Biological Process: one-carbon compound metabolic process (GO:0006730);Expression=AK059712
chr11   RAP3_rep    CDS 17567891    17568694    .   -   .   Parent=Os11t0455500-01;
chr11   RAP3_rep    CDS 17566493    17567029    .   -   .   Parent=Os11t0455500-01;
chr11   RAP3_rep    CDS 17566191    17566400    .   -   .   Parent=Os11t0455500-01;
```

and program

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream.GetField;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sample
{
 public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
 {
   Sample s=new Sample();
   String inputID="Os11t0120200-01";

   //System.out.println("Enter the value");
   //Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   //n=sc.nextLong();

   ArrayList<String> IDlist=new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> InputIDlist=new ArrayList<String>();
   int n;
   try
   {
     File nf=new File("textfile1.txt");
     FileOutputStream fop1=new FileOutputStream(nf,true);
     String os ="";

     FileInputStream fis1=new FileInputStream("chr11.gb");
     FileInputStream fis2=new FileInputStream("1.txt");
     InputStreamReader in1 = new InputStreamReader(fis1, "UTF-8");
     InputStreamReader in2 = new InputStreamReader(fis2, "UTF-8");
     BufferedReader input1 = new BufferedReader(in1);
     BufferedReader input2 =  new BufferedReader(in2);

     String line1;
     String line2;

     FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("chr11.GB");
     InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(in);
     String line;

     File f=new File("1.GB");
     FileOutputStream fop=new FileOutputStream(f);

     if(f.exists())
     {
        os="This data is written through the program\t\n";
        fop1.write(os.getBytes());

        String str1="";
        String str2="";
        os="The data has been written\t\n";
        fop1.write(os.getBytes());

        while((line=input.readLine())!=null)
        {
          String splits[]=line.split("\t");
          if(splits[2].equalsIgnoreCase("mrna"))
          {
            IDlist.add((splits[8]));
          }
        }

        while((line=input2.readLine())!=null)
        {
          String splits[]=line.split("\t");
          if(splits[0]!="")
          {
            InputIDlist.add((splits[0]));
          }
        }
        for(int j=0; j<InputIDlist.size(); j++)
        {
          for(int i=0; i<IDlist.size(); i++)
          {
            if((IDlist.get(i).substring(3, 18).toString()).equals(InputIDlist.get(j)))
            {
              if(IDlist.get(i).contains("Alias"))
              {
                 os=IDlist.get(i).substring(IDlist.get(i).lastIndexOf("Alias"),IDlist.get(i).lastIndexOf("ID_converter"))+"\t\n";
                 fop1.write(os.getBytes());
              }
              if(IDlist.get(i).contains("Biological Process"))
              {
                 //n=IDlist.get(i).lastIndexOf("Biological Process");
                 os=IDlist.get(i).substring(IDlist.get(i).lastIndexOf("Biological Process"),IDlist.get(i).lastIndexOf(";"))+"\t\n";
                 fop1.write(os.getBytes());
              }
              if(IDlist.get(i).contains("Molecular Function"))
              {
                 //n=IDlist.get(i).lastIndexOf("Molecular Function");
                 os=IDlist.get(i).substring(IDlist.get(i).lastIndexOf("Molecular Function"), IDlist.get(i).lastIndexOf(","))+"\t\n";
                 fop1.write(os.getBytes());
              }
              break;
            }
            String p="\n";
            fop1.write(p.getBytes());
          }
        }
     }
     else
     {
        System.out.println("This file is not exist");
     }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: You've posted a huge amount of data and a huge amount of code, but not said where you're getting the exception, either in terms of which line it's reading or where it's happening in the code. There are various things wrong with the code (to start with, you're never closing anything as far as I can see, and you're using the default encoding to write to the file, which is rarely a good idea - use an OutputStreamWriter with the appropriate encoding instead) but it's hard to pin down *exactly* what's wrong without the really *useful* information about where things are failing.

Comment: Where is *javascript* involved here?

Comment: Doesn't the program tell you the LINE NUMBER of the code that threw the exception?

Comment: error is in 86th liine and my input wil be ID=Os11t0455500-01

Comment: And which line is the 86th line?  Or do you expect us to count them?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments on the question, but I'll still try a guess:

Most likely, it is the following file (due to **String**IndexOutOfBoundsException): `IDlist.get(i).substring(3, 18)`. If this is shorter, you'd get that exception.

A reason for this might be this part:

```
if(splits[0]!="")  
{
   InputIDlist.add((splits[0]));
}
```

If `splits[0]` is empty, `==` might still not be true (and thus `!=` might be true). Use `!splits[0].equals("")` here (or better `!"".equals(splits[0])` to account for the possibility that `splits[0]` might ever be null). Note that `==` checks for reference equality, i.e. do both references point to the same object (in terms of C++, is it the same pointer), whereas `equals` checks for logical equality (might be differently implemented for each object).

Edit:

Another possibility for that exception would be one of those lines:

```
os=IDlist.get(i).substring(IDlist.get(i).lastIndexOf("Alias"),IDlist.get(i).lastIndexOf("ID_converter"))
```

You check for "Alias", so `lastIndexOf("Alias")` should not return -1, but `IDlist.get(i).lastIndexOf("ID_converter")` might. If so, you are out of bounds.

Edit 2:

Yet another thing: Even if both Strings ("Alias" and "ID_converter") are in the source string, but in the wrong order ("ID_converter .... Alias"), you'd get that exception as well, since then `begin index > end index` which is not allowed (please read the JavaDoc on String.substring()).

Comment: Instead of `!string.equals("")` or `!"".equals(string)` I suggest to use the better readable version `string.length() > 0`.

Comment: Well, `string.length()` could result in an NPE if `string`is null. If apache commons lang is an option, `StringUtils.isNotEmpty(string)` would be even better (since it returns false for null and ""), or even `StringUtils.isNotBlank(string)` (returns false for null, "" and any string containing just whitespace).

Comment: Sure, if the string can be null, then `string != null && string.length() > 0` IMHO still is more readable than the C-like `!"".equals(string)`. But the not-null-safe `!string.equals("")` can be replaced easily with the not-null-safe variant `string.length() > 0`.

Comment: @mklhmnn Yes, you could replace that. Additionally, `!"".equals(string)` would return true if string is null, so you'd need to check for that anyway. Thus my suggestion to use the Apache commons-lang `StringUtils` methods, which IMHO are the most readable version.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (IDlist.get(i).contains("Alias"))
```

To:

```
if ((IDlist.get(i).contains("Alias")) && (IDlist.get(i).contains("ID_converter")))
```

Any set a breakpoint to check why is the second condition is false if it doesnt go in to the if statement then.

Comment: `and` is not a Java keyword, use `&&` instead.